# The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: wcf

I used Clear Image Com dll to make a Image processing service libray.
I have a interface Imagery for service contract which contains a methodLoadBitmapFromFile(imgFileName). My service class overrides this method and use clear image com dll and its method to cropping an image.
further I created a Windows form for consume this service but when

```
Imagery img;
 img = new ServiceReference1.ImageryClient();

 img.LoadBitmapFromFile(imgFileName);
  pictureBox1.Image = img.GetBitmap();
```

Imagery is my  service contract.I create a the service which refers as ServiceReference1.
LoadBitmapFromFile(imgFileName)--this method is actually defined in service class.
when it call from client I get following error:

```
{"The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly."}
```

what is wrong in my case? 
Is it the problem of using Com dll in service layer.?
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add try catch block to capture exception and than create a new connection. Possible cause could be timeout.